# MacOS 10.13.6 - Anaconda won't launch Spyder: Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: installation, anaconda, spyder

I have MacOS 10.13.6 and downloaded Anaconda (via the Install Wizard not command line). It took many hours and finally said "Installation Failed," but Anaconda launched anyway. When I try to launch Spyder (5.4.3), nothing would happen at first. Then after a few tries, I started to get a window that read the Segmentation Fault 11 error.

I have deleted and redownloaded Anaconda a couple times. No change. I updated to the most recent version of Anaconda after installing, no change. I have tried uninstalling Spyder and reinstalling, even downgrading, nothing works. After reading some other threads from people with the same error message, I tried the following in the Command Terminal:

`spyder`

`conda config --set auto_activate_base False`

`conda update conda`

This resulted in a few messages that said:

```
\ WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(52): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.                                               
  environment location: /Users/danielle/anaconda3
  registry file: /Users/danielle/.conda/environments.txt
```

I still tried the following anyway:

`//anaconda3/bin/spyder.command`

It says: 'command not found'

I've since reset it to the default:

`conda config --set auto_activate_base True`

I then tried:

`conda create -n spyder-cf -c conda-forge spyder jupyter_client=7.3.1`

And got:

```
Preparing transaction: done                                                     
Verifying transaction: - WARNING conda.core.path_actions:verify(1055): Unable to create environments file. Path not writable.                                   
  environment location: /Users/danielle/.conda/environments.txt                                                                                               
done     
                                                                       
Executing transaction: \ WARNING conda.core.envs_manager:register_env(55): Unable to register environment. Path not writable or missing.                        
  environment location: /Users/danielle/anaconda3/envs/spyder-cf                
  registry file: /Users/danielle/.conda/environments.txt                        
done
```

But regardless, I tried:

`conda activate spyder-cf`

`spyder`

And got:

```
/Users/danielle/anaconda3/envs/spyder-cf/bin/pythonw: line 3: 25192 Segmentation fault: 11  /Users/danielle/anaconda3/envs/spyder-cf/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python "$@"
```

I'm not super familiar with computers, I have tried reading other threads, but it's all foreign to me. Is my MacOS simply too old for Spyder? Can someone please help me? I'm desperate.